# Inertia get request does not update $page.props

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs3, inertiajs

**Quick description:**

My problem is, that the code `Inertia.get(route("home"), { q: query }, {preserveState: false});` does not update the vue 3 state. My home Controller looks like this:

```
class HomeController extends Controller
{
    public function show(Request $request) {
        $test = $request->input('q');
        return Inertia::render('Home', [
            'test' => $test,
        ]);
    }
}
```

The code works just fine, but only if I reload the page with an existing query like `www.my-website.de/?q=abc`. But if I trigger the reload using the Inertia code from above, the vue 3 state does not update. I have checked this, using the vue chrome devtool.

**Extensive description:**
I am trying to build a search functionality for my website. I am using Laravel (version 9.2) Jetstream (version 2.7) with Inertia (version 0.11.0) and Vue-3. I want to pass my search query via a get request, because then it is included in the url, in case somebody wants to copy & paste the url. Right now I want to test, how I can get the search results from the server when I submit a new query using Inertia.

**Edit:**
I did find out that whenever I use `Inertia.get(route("home"), { q: query }, {preserveState: false});` to reload the page, then the server does send the right props in the response, however they do not end up in vue. I do think it has something to do with versioning, because if I try this with different queries the version in the response does not change. I did read this [enter link description here](https://inertiajs.com/the-protocol) about asset versioning in Inertia. However I could not find out, why the version does not change.

**"Solution":**
I did found out that I can access the prop using $page.props. I was confused because in the vue devtools there are several components: "Root" -> in this is "Inertia" -> in this is in my case "Home". I was looking at the `Inertia.initialPage.props.test`. However I should have looked at `Home.attrs.test` or `Home.props.test` (depending on whether or not you have the component defined).

Can anybody tell me, what is the `Inertia.initialPage.props` good for and why am I accessing `Home.attrs.test` when writing `{{ $page.props.test }}` in my `Home.vue` file?

Comment: Try $request->query('q')

Comment: Thanks for your reply, however this did not solve the problem. Using "query" delivered exactly the same results as using "input"